# Confused about an answer for maximal cliques

Tags: graph-theory

I had a question in one of my classes and I am not sure if I misunderstood the answer or if I have the concept wrong in my mind. We were given a graph (see below) and asked whether or not the number of maximal $3$-cliques in the graph was $2$. I believed it to be true, with the $2$ maximal cliques being $(1,2,3)$ and $(1,2,7)$. The answer was false (or that is what I have written down, I took the class last year and have no way of checking with instructor). Can anyone confirm this answer or tell me what I am missing?

[image]

Comment: I guess it's not really clear (at least to me) what is meant by a maximal $3$-clique? Maximal in what sense?

Comment: As I recall, a maximal clique was a subgraph where all vertices connected to all other vertices. Maximum clique would be the largest in the graph, in this example (3,4,5,6).

Comment: I know what a maximal clique is, but what is a maximal $3$-clique? Of course no $K_3$ can be strictly contained in another.

Comment: My apologies, a 3 clique was considered to be a subgraph of only 3 vertices that were all connected.

Comment: But my confusion is what is a "maximal $3$-clique" (the whole phrase)? The word maximal usually refers to some kind of containment, and it is trivial that no $K_3$ can be contained in another $K_3$, so I don't understand why the word maximal is being added to $3$-clique.

Comment: I would probably interpret the phrase maximal 3-clique to mean a 3-clique that is not contained in a 4-clique

Comment: Maximal indicating that to add another vertex would no longer make it a clique. To me, adding vertex 6 or 3 to the subgraph (1,2,7) would no longer allow it to be a clique. That makes (1,2,7) the largest clique it can be with those vertices so it is the maximal clique, which happens to be a maximal 3-clique.

Comment: @KelvinSoh that would be reasonable, but in that case cdd's answer would be correct.

Comment: Based off of this discussion, I would believe I either heard the instructor wrong when I took the class, or she was incorrect to begin with. I have looked at this several times since then and it never made sense. Thank you for the discussion and easing my mind.

Comment: @cdd The question is: does maximal 3 clique means a 3-clique which cannot be extended to a four? Or does it mean a clique which is maximal in the graph. In the second interpretation the answer would be 0....

Comment: Maximal 3-clique was used to define a part of a graph where 3 nodes were connected and there is no fourth node you could add and still be a clique. So, while (3,4,5) is a 3-clique, it is not a maximal 3-clique as you could add 6 and have a 4-clique. (1,2,3) is a maximal 3-clique because adding any of the other nodes would no longer allow the subgraph to be a clique. That is how I remember it being defined in the class, but again, it has been a while.